# Is possible to estimate the value of the following integration.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, numerical-methods, lebesgue-integral

I need to estimate this integration $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$.
Is possible to estimate ?

Comment: The integral diverges to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

No $$I-=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{dx}{(x-a)^\alpha}$$ is an improper integral which is finite if $\alpha <1$ and infinite if $\alpha\ge 1$